# Fire an event in c#

Tags: c#, events, slider

What I want to do is fire the ValueChanged event for a slider.  How would I do this?

I do not want to call the ValueChanged event handler directly.

I'm actually trying to fire the event as if the user were adjusting the slider on the UI.

Comment: Why don't you just change the value, then?

Comment: are you doing this for testing - are you trying to simulate the event being raised? If so, reflection can help. I can give an answer to that effect.

Comment: Please read below.... I get into detail when someone else asked the same good question.

Comment: The reason I'm wanting to fire an event is to get a mediaelement to behave correctly.  Firing the event makes it work.... setting a value does not.

Answer (score 1):

Raising other objects' events can be quite helpful in testing. The following code can achieve that:

```
class SomeClass
{
  public event Action SomeEvent;
}

// later
var instance = new SomeClass();
instance.SomeEvent += () => Console.WriteLine("it happeneed");

var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
var type = typeof(SomeClass);
var field = type.GetField("SomeEvent", flags);
var method = field.FieldType.GetProperty("Method", flags);
var target = field.FieldType.GetProperty("Target", flags);
var methodInstance = field.GetValue(instance);
((MulticastDelegate)methodInstance).DynamicInvoke(new object[] { });
```

Comment: You can stop me.... come up with a better solution. ;)  I'm not sure how the above would work.  Will have to look at it some.

Comment: @spender I'll point out this is best done for testing purposes.

Comment: @Payo: Having read about your predicament (probably best added as an edit to your question), it seems "dark corner" applies here.

Comment: Thanks for the help btw. I'm not looking to trigger an event for a class I wrote. I'm looking to trigger it for a Slider. Would this work for the Slider?

Comment: @user1435769 yes, it works for anything. that's the beauty of reflection :)

Comment: @spender don't sprain your ankle coming off your high horse, bud. learning reflection is both challenging and rewarding. Obviously, we should use it appropriately (e.g. testing/mocking), as is the case for every programming tool.

Comment: Sorry @payo, my comment was mis-addressed and was meant for the original poster. It's meant to be an acknowledgement that for their particular problem, reflection might well be appropriate. Given the lack of context in the original question, I don't think it's unreasonable to remind the questioner that there's usually a better solution to using reflection in production code (as opposed to test code) because it can be brittle and isn't particularly type-safe

Comment: @spender very well stated! I hope the OP can find a cleaner solution, to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

What you describe can't really be done.  Events can only be fired from within the class where they are declared.

Why do you need to fire the ValueChanged event anyway?  It sounds like this task is something for the DataModel or ViewModel and not the slider.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not a proposed answer.  It doesn't pose a possible solution or work around.  Please edit to propose some form of useful information or approach or delete and post as a comment on the question.

Comment: @VulgarBinary. IMO, telling the questioner that it can't be done is valid, especially as it is correct.

Comment: When you programatically change the value of the slider a different set of events seem to fire than when the user actually grabs it and slides it.  It is these missing events that I want to emulate.

Comment: The reason for this is that I have this slider adjusting the speedratio of a mediaelement.  There is a bug in the mediaelement.  When the mediaelements position is changed the speedratio although set to 2.0 is playing at 1.0 speed.  I noticed that when I move the slider during playback that whatever events fire seem to get the mediaelement to pay attention to the speedratio value again.  I'm just trying to do a simple workaround here.

Comment: @spender - mocking can accomplish what he's trying to do.  If I had the time I'd type up the answer.  The answer of "it cannot be done" is false, unproductive, and overly not helpful.